# How collect values of a specified key recursively in a Array/Hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, function, recursion, hash

I have the following Array (no limit of deepness) :

```
 [
   {
     name: "foo",
     age: 12,
     children: [{
         name: "zoo",
         age: 44
       },
       {
         name: "taz",
         age: 17,
         children: [{
             name: 'tof',
             age: 23
           },
           {
             name: 'tok',
             age: 42
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     name: "bar",
     age: 54
   }
 ]
```

And I would like to collect all the different values of the key `name`, in this example the result would be:

(the order does not matter)

```
['foo', 'zoo', 'taz', 'tof', 'tok', 'bar']
```

with a function like

```
def func(my_array, "name")
```

Do you have any idea how I should code that function ?

Comment: Are you just trying to collect all the leaf-nodes that are strings?

Comment: nope, all the different values with key "name"

Comment: the array you provided is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way of doing it using `case` to differentiate between the various object types you'll encounter:

```
def find_names(object, key_name)
  case (object)
  when Array
    object.flat_map do |e|
      find_names(e, key_name)
    end
  when Hash
    [ object[key_name] ] + find_names(object.values, key_name).compact
  end
end
```

Comment: why do you have `object` in brackets? It is just for me, may be there is something to having it in `()`

Comment: It's not necessary to use the brackets. I just have them there for utmost clarity.

Comment: The example didn't have any, but that's easy to accommodate.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you know the substructure is under `:children`:

```
def extract(sequence, key)
  sequence.flat_map do |hash|
    [hash[key], *extract(hash[:children] || [], key)]
  end
end
```

Comment: Given the statement of the question, it seems to me that there is no reasonable alternative to your assumption.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, it could be the case that OP wants to iterate over all values, which are iterable.

Answer (score 2):

Heres a fast but brittle regex way of doing it

```
def find_nested(arr, key)
  arr.to_s.scan(/#{key.to_sym}=>"([^"]+)/).flatten
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_em(arr)
  arr.each_with_object([]) do |h,a|
    a << h[:name]
    a.concat(find_em(h[:children])) if h.key?(:children)
  end
end

find_em(arr)
  #=> ["foo", "zoo", "taz", "tof", "tok", "bar"]
```

Comment: Worked the first time!